# c# Creating MDI Child of Form1 from Form2

Tags: c#, mdichild, mdiparent

I am attempting to instantiate an instance of From3 as a child of Form1 by clicking a button on Form2.

However, when using the following code in Form2:

```
Form3 PFForm = new Form3();
PFForm.MdiParent = Form1;
PFForm.Show();
```

... to instantiate Form3 as a child of Form1 I get the error:

"'Form1' is a type, which is not valid in the given context."

Answer (score 1):

Is Form2 also a child of Form1?

If yes, then:

```
Form3 PFForm = new Form3();
PFForm.MdiParent = this.MdiParent;
PFForm.Show();
```

Comment: @TripIves since you're new here, please remember to mark the answer, which helped you the most, as accepted answer. (Instead of renaming the question to Resolved)